# Android - opening series of activities after restart

Tags: android, persistence, android-activity, android-lifecycle

there is my situation. I have same activities which goes one by another, no matter what they are doing. Lets name them from the start of alphabet. When users uses my application, he goes through activities and makes his own path between them, so he could with back button go back in respecitve back order.

He starts with act. A - D - F and with back button he goes back as from F to D and A. Ok. Now, when Android system resolves the application is no longer in use or needs lot of RAM in some particular time, system kills it. My goal is to find, how to restore application to its former state including order of opened activities?

It might not be clear, so here is the example:

User has open activities A (login) - D - F - G, minimize it, after some time, app is killed. When he start this application again, he needs to login at activity A and than he has to see activity G (= he was there last time), and when he push back button, he will go do activity F, then activity D and so on... Is like revieving an row of activites. I know I have to persist all the information stored in my activities (D, F, G), but is it acutally possible to persist app state like that?

Thanks for any comment on this

**Solution:**

I am tracking flag, which identifies the state my application is in. If it is s 0, it means I am opening new activity normally. On start of each activity I put into shared preferences string, which contains all my activity history. Each activity has it's own id (again sharedPref).  In another shared pref I am saving as a String formular data (or data with GUI), when onPause occurs. I set flag as a 1. When app starts and flag is 1, I revive application stack from sharedPref. Set data for each of them from another Shared Pref. And that's it, application state is revived :-)

Comment: Its not that nobody knows. I don't know why this isn't answered. I'll write you up one tomorrow, as I am getting sleepy and this one is a little longer than my brain can handle at the moment.

Comment: @Waypoint, 1 - The activities are created from the same class?, If yes, What differentiates one activity from another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can persist anything you need to, it just a matter of how and what is going to be beneficial. There are multiple techniques that have been used to persist state over the years. Nearly all of them are available to you, but will require careful management on your part. Depending on what your application does, there may be special tricks available to you, as well.

**Step 1**

Determine what each Activity needs in order to run effectively. Determine what you can recalculate and what you absolutely should not recalculate. For instance, if one of your Activities is a Cursor Adapter of some kind and works according to a key to a table, you don't need to persist the entire Activity, you simply need to hold onto whichever `_id` relates to that particular Activity run.

**Step 2**

Since you are wanting to track Activity history, you will need some representation of that history. What you are proposing is a stack model, so you will want to write your own stack object and find an easy way to identify each activity in that stack. Do not try and save the actual Activity references as this will invariably lead to leaks. You can then save this stack to a database, shared preferences, file or even parcel it to a bundle. Integer constants that identify each Activity might be one way to accomplish this.

**Step 3**

Decide on your method of save, and build the appropriate save and load methods for your stack and each Activity.

**Step 4**

Override the Back button to retrieve the top Activity identifier and its appropriate data on the stack. (As a note: your stack might be better placed in an extended `Application`) Then start the next `Activity` with its required data.

**Step 5**

When your "login" Activity (or Application) starts, load the stack. When authentication completes, reload the top Activity on the stack, passing its required data through Intent Extras. You don't have to open ALL of the Activities at once, just the ones that the user is on.

**Step 6**
In your `onCreate` or `onWindowAttached` for each `Activity`, have it add itself to the stack. In your `onDestroy` for each `Activity`, have it remove itself from the stack.  Since you are persisting your data, you can easily `finish()` to indicate that the `Activity` is complete.

**Step 7**

In your `onPause` for each `Activity` have it save the state that you feel is important. You can even save the scroll position and just have it rescroll when the `Activity` restarts. In your `onCreate` have it regain its state via the extras that you supplied.

It is really as simple as all of that. If you need some samples, I can gladly provide.

FuzzicalLogic

Comment: Thanks, by the time, I have put and bounty, I have resolved it myself. Solution is added to the main topic for others. I did id myself using shared preferences, tracking id of my activites and saving them and their values to Strings. 50+ for you by the way :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all you need to do is reconstruct the path of activities from A to Z (or whatever), you don't need to make things too complicated.  if you want to do it the right way, do the suggestion by Fuzzical Logic.  if you want to get it running quickly and complicate things after that, you can start with this simple method.

Basically, you map each activity to a code, and maintain a simple text file.  Each time an activity is invoked, it should append it's code to the text file.  So you're really just writing to a file exactly what you explained in your question.  In your example, you'd have "ADFG" in a text file.

When you exit an activity and go back, just read the file, chop off the last letter, and write it out.  In your example, if you had "ADFG", pressed back, the file would now contain "ADF".

When your app starts, simply read the file and for each character, create the associated activity as you would normally.  Read the file once and pass the string to each activity as it is created.  So the root activity would read "A" and start that activity (passing the string "DFG" in the bundle), then that activity would read the next character and start the D activity (passing "FG"), and so on until the last activity sees that there's no characters left in the string.

Once that's all working, you can worry about how to store state information for each activity.  Fuzzy's solution is by far the most elegant, but elegant and ASAP don't usually mix, so it's your call.  I'd separate the stack data from the state data for each item in the stack.  It's just easier that way IMO.

Hope that helps!